# Dynamic validation on MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-validation

This **works fine**

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(Area_Validation))]
 public partial class Area
 {
    ...
 }

 public class Area_Validation
 {
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please add this field.")] 
 public int Email { get; set; }

 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please add this field")]
 public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

**but how about** if `Area_Validation` is **dynamically created**? for example *Subscription Fields* that on back-end can be created by the user and end up like this:

[image]

How can I set the **Metadata** on each field for **auto validation**?

Currently I'm doing:

```
public class SubscriberFormViewModel
{
    public List<SubscriberFieldModel> Fields { get; private set; }
    public Calendar Calendar { get; private set; }
    public Company Company { get; private set; }

    public SubscriberFormViewModel()
    { 
        // TODO: This is only for testing while validation is not set
    }
    public SubscriberFormViewModel(Decimal calendarId)
    {
        if (calendarId > 0)
        {
            SubscribersRepository db = new SubscribersRepository();

            Calendar calendar = db.GetCalendarById(calendarId);
            Company company = db.GetCompanyById(calendar.company_id);

            this.Fields = db.FindAllSubscriberFieldsByCalendar(calendarId);
            this.Calendar = calendar;
            this.Company = company;
        }
        else
            this.Fields = new List<SubscriberFieldModel>();
    }
}
```

and I want to set the **Metadata** in all `Fields` property

In other words, this `Fields` are filled up from the Database and can have several types, can be a `string`, `number`, `dropdown`, etc ... kinda like MailChimp Fields Properties:

[image]

**is there a way to do this programmaticaly** or I need to create a jQuery plugin to validate it and stop using use validation from MVC2 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can do this using Data Annotations attributes.

There is a project in Codeplex, called [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) that permit you to add validation rules in a fluent way using .Net code. I never used that project but it seems that maybe can help you in your case with dynamically created objects.

Hope it helps!

Comment: howdy again :) I was thinking just to add some jQuery on it to validate using a class naming convention, as I know what the type and if it's required... This all just to do it using javascript, as in the controller I can always return the error, just wanted to do things right and save a round trip to the server :) - **I will** have a look at this project.

Comment: Well... please keep me updated on this! Also have a look at this jQuery plugin: `http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/`. It integrates seamlessly with asp.net mvc and is a very good plugin that can help with your requirement...

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can make several validation scenarios, one per type(or more per type if you need). Then Add this validation rules on type creation. When you need to validate, you can call template Validate method, that will check if these rules and if not - will add errors to ModelState, that you will be able to show on front end.

Actually its not that profitable to add any attributes, as attributes pro is that you can decorate your type with them. When you are doing some dynamic things, you`d better have some dynamic way to add validation.